# Set pull up/down resistor on Beaglebone Black

Tags: beagleboneblack

I was trying to make a simple push button and led with BBB, and I successed to make it work. But my question is, the led supposed to be turned off before I press the button, but with this the led is automatically turned on when I run the code, and turned off when I press the button. I'm trying to set the pull up/down resistor by  `cd /sys/class/gpio/gpio44/ - echo 0 > value` but its  "operation not permitted" warning always appears. Can someone help me? Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

void sig_handler(int signo)
{
    if (signo == SIGINT)
    printf("\nRecieved SIGINT\n");
    exit(1);
}

void GPIOREAD(char *url, char* val)
{
    FILE *path = fopen(url,"r");
    fread(val, 2, 1, path);
    fclose(path);
}

int main(void) 
{

    int status;
    unsigned int cnt=0;

    status = access("/sys/class/gpio/gpio44/value", F_OK );
    if (status == -1)
        {
            //file doesnt exist
            printf("GPIO_44 file doesnt exist dude\n");
            exit(1);
        } 

    status = access("/sys/class/gpio/gpio45/value", F_OK ); 
    if (status == -1)
        {
            //file doesnt exist
            printf("GPIO_45 file doesnt exist dude\n");
            exit(1);
        }


    //set GPIO 45 as output
    system("echo in > /sys/class/gpio/gpio44/direction");
    system("echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio45/direction");
    sleep(1);

    char val[10];

    while(1)
        {
            GPIOREAD("/sys/class/gpio/gpio44/value", val);
            printf("BUTTON STAT %s\n", val);

            if(!strcmp(val,"1\n"))
            {
                printf("%u) AAA LED --- ON\n", cnt);
                system("echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio45/value");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%u) AAA LED --- OFF\n", cnt);
                system("echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio45/value");
            }
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running as root?  Typically the files in /sys/class/gpio are owned by root, so you might simply have a permissions problem.  Within your code, the mix of file operations and system(3) is unusual.  Might be happier focusing on file ops only (but still must run as root).  Good luck.

Comment: i already run it as root, but still.. it keep showin me that warning, even the file inside it already rwx

Comment: OK, good to know.  How about the GPIO direction?  It must be "out" or will not allow you to update value.

Comment: i already set that to be input, but the default value is 1 not 0